# Two same processor having different base clock but same turbo boost needs same cooling solution or different?

Tags: laptop, cpu, cooling, clockspeed

Suppose a processor (ex 11th gen 1135g7 with Intel speedstep tech)  have configurable up and down frequency. If in **one laptop *base clock is 1.4Ghz*** (due to configurable tdp down) with **turbo@4.2ghz** and in **another laptop with same processor with base clock is 2.4Ghz** with **turbo@4.2Ghz**.My ques is

1. Will both processor needs same cooling solution as thier turbo @4.2Ghz is same or Second laptop base@2.4ghz needs higher grade cooling system bcoz its base clock is more???
2. Is second laptop (base@2.4) is more powerful than first one(base@1.4Ghz)???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very open to interpretation, and the question largely comes down to "what are you trying to achieve?"  Below are some statements which may be helpful, and, I suspect are as close as anyone can come to giving you an answer -

- Any non-ancient Intel CPU will automatically thermally throttle if it gets to hot so as not to damage the CPU.  This means you can run the identical solution for both CPU's and they will work - albeit more slowly - even if the the cooling solution is inadequate.
- The cooler the CPU, the happier it is. Although its likely academic in theory at least, the cooler the CPU the longer it will last.
- The base clock is the maximum **sustained** clock speed (compared to the turbo speed which is a boost speed) - however the CPU will only run at this speed when required - otherwise it will run slower.    Depending on how you define "more powerful", yes, the second laptop will be more powerful - although this additional power will only be noticeable on sustained work loads.
- You can get away with less cooling on the second CPU as it has a lower TDP, so it needs to dissipate less heat.  That said, if you ran the same lesser power on the system with the higher TDP it would work, but the system would throttle to lower speeds because the CPU would get hot.
- You will get more out of turbo boost by having better cooling regardless of the system.
- A lower base clock will typically draw less power.

As an annecdote from a long time ago, I run a first gen I5 CPU as a home router - it was way overkill.   I landed up underclocking it to save power and to use passive cooling.  (ie same CPU, same heatsink but no fan)

Comment: I would caution using desktop processors without active cooling, they were definitely not designed in that mind, there certainly are processors that were.  I especially would avoid Core processors without active cooling unless you seriously know what you doing (Core processors run hot).

Comment: @Ramhound - do you know of any problems with any Intel CPU made in the last 10 years have died from overheating? (I agree that running a desktop CPU without active cooling without knowing what you are doing is not a great idea, but I dont think it will kill the cpu)

Comment: I have never know an Intel processor (desktop) to run without a fan, so I can’t  say I have, since I have a sample size of 1 (from your story but that was successful)

Comment: What i wanted to know that when both laptop has no workload then both will be on lowest frequency (lower than thier base frequency), it means they dissipate same level of heat at idle condation. True???? Also, when there is workload both will increase their frequency, so heat and power consumption will increase accordingly on both. So what  lowering TDP has played here its role???? I am just curious to know where i am wrong here. I have bought a laptop with 11th gen i5 base@2.4Ghz. But what i seen the more higher prices laptop has its lower thier tdp at base@1.4Ghz with speedstep enabled.

Comment: Yes, when idle at low clock speed they both use the same  power=same heat dissipation. When workload increases its likely the 2.4ghz will increase more and use more power (for a shorter period). Lowering tdp allows for less cooling=less noise and size.

Comment: Thanks for a satisfactory answer.